# ¿Como saber cuando necesito rellenar bytes vacíos entre los miembros o al final de una estructura?

Tags: c

Sé que esto lo hace el compilador, pero me gustaría entender lo que haría el compilador por mí.
Por ejemplo:

```
struct  MixedData
{
    short z;
    char x;
    char y;
};

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(struct MixedData));
    return 0;
}
```

El tamaño de la estructura sería: 4
¿Por qué dio ese resultado? y cual sería sus posibles direcciones de memoria?
También tengo otra duda, cuando tengo un array de estructuras es necesario siempre hacer algún relleno?
Y también estoy confundido con los términos de "alineamiento" y "relleno".
Lo que tengo entendido, es que "alineamiento" hace referencia a la forma como están ubicados cada miembro en la memoria y el relleno son los bytes necesarios para calcular la dirección de memoria del miembro que le sigue a un X miembro.
No sé si estoy en lo correcto o no.
También estaba viendo que el compilador necesita alinear la estructura para que sea mas eficiente para la CPU, pero que pasaría si no lo alineará como se debe? Alguien me podría explicar algún ejemplo demostrando su in-eficiencia?

Comment: Se han escrito libros enteros sobre esto ... *casi casi* demasiado para una sola pregunta ...

Comment: Y por eso no me puedes ayudar con mis preguntas?

Comment: Página de la ayuda, [¿Qué tipo de preguntas debo evitar preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), 3er párrafo: `Tus preguntas deben tener un alcance razonable. Si puedes imaginar un libro entero que responde tu pregunta, estás pidiendo demasiado.`

Comment: Creo que es una pregunta válida. Si @MrDave1999 se hubiera imaginado *un libro entero* no tendría nada que preguntar. Muchas veces para darse cuenta de la profundidad de un tema hay que empezar por hacer preguntas básicas o superficiales.

Comment: @gustavovelascoh si el AP por el desconocimiento del tema o por algun otro motivo no conoce cuanto abarca su pregunta entonces el juego esta de nuestra parte para guiarlo ha delimitar su pregunta, por ejemplo en vez de hacer solo una publicación puede hacer varias como un seguimiento al anterior, asi no tendria que dar un contexto completo para cada caso sino enlazarlo a la anterior.

Comment: @MrDave1999 Te recomiendo no crear muchas preguntas es una sola publicación ya que tiende a recibir menos ayuda, ¿y por qué tiende a recibir menos ayuda? no sea porque tus preguntas sea buena o mala sino que es dificil que alguien se tome el tiempo de responder todas las preguntas ya que involucraria mucha búsqueda para fundamentarla correctamente, mucho tiempo para tipearla, etc. Al menos IMHO no la responderia, miro y sigo mi camino. Lo aconsejable en estos casos es crear una pregunta por cada publicación asi obtendras una respuesta por cada uno con una fundamentación correcta y precisa.

Comment: @eyllanesc Si tienes razón, para la próxima duda lo haré en diferentes publicaciones, así se entiende mejor. Disculpa por la molestia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ¿Por qué dio ese resultado?

Tienes un dato de tipo short (2 bytes) y 2 char (2 * 1 byte), esto suma 4 bytes.

> cuales serían sus posibles direcciones de memoria?

Suponiendo un sistema de 64-bits

```
&MixedData = 0xAABBCC00
&(MixedData.z) = 0xAABBCC00
&(MixedData.x) = 0xAABBCC02
&(MixedData.y) = 0xAABBCC03
```

> "alineamiento" y "relleno"

Supongamos la siguiente estructura:

```
struct  NewStruct
{
    uint8_t z;  // 1byte
    uint32_t x; // 4bytes
    uint16_t y; // 2bytes
};
```

En un sistema de 32 bits quedaria en memoria:

```
struct  NewStruct
{
    uint8_t z;  // 1byte
    uint8_t z_padd[3];  // 3byte - para alineacion de los miembros
    uint32_t x; // 4bytes
    uint16_t y; // 2bytes
    uint8_t y_padd[2];  // 2byte - para alineacion en arreglos
}; // Total: 12 bytes
```

Ahora, si la estructura se declara de la siguiente manera:

```
struct  NewStruct
{
    uint32_t x; // 4bytes
    uint16_t y; // 2bytes
    uint8_t z;  // 1byte
};
```

En un sistema de 32 bits quedaria en memoria:

```
struct  NewStruct
{
    uint32_t x; // 4bytes
    uint16_t y; // 2bytes
    uint8_t z;  // 1byte
    uint8_t z_padd[1];  // 1byte - para alineacion en arreglos
}; // Total: 8 bytes
```

Aquí hay un [articulo en inglés](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/) que explica con más detalle y paso a paso con ejemplos este tema del alineamiento y relleno (*Alignment and padding*).

Por otra parte, la opcion de "*packing*" es provista por algunos compiladores para forzar el no uso del *padding*. El problema de esta opcion es que el codigo generado para acceder a direcciones no alineadas puede no ser óptimo y contener bugs. Además se pierde compatibilidad ya que algunas arquitecturas no soportan esta funcionalidad.

Espero haya podido aclarar un poco el tema.